# which data storage option is preferable in this sceanario

Tags: android, database, google-maps

I have a google map where the user can tap and mark a coordinate. User can mark around 10-20 location. I need this coordinates to be used later. So these coordinates are needed to be save using a method of data storage of android. Plus store data in web can't be used. So which left is:

-Shared Preferences

-Internal Storage

-SQLite Databases

I am confused which method should be used for my case. It will be helpful if anyone provides with code and explanation.

Comment: If you more data then you refer `SQLite`.

Comment: but i need only two field lat and long of a coordinate

Comment: Actually your question is not clear. Here you said `the user can tap and mark a coordinate` So user can tap on multiple locations(i mean multiple times) or one location(only one time)?

Comment: Now another question you want to saved this locations until the app online? or still in offline??

Comment: consider data will be saved always in offline

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76763/discussion-between-m-d-and-fay007).

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based.  Moreover, the request for "gimmeh teh codez" probably makes it too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to used your app in offline mode then `SQLite` is best potion for you. It persists all the data in offline. When you open app again it'll load all the data from `SQLite`.

Here you can find way how to implement `SQLite`

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Personally I'd just store a JSON array as a string in SharedPreferences. Unless the OP already has the base code for handling a SQLite database, the code would be much easier.